# Create a new file with Sublime Text 3 via CLI

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, sublimetext3

Is it possible with Sublime Text 3 to create a new file in the current working directory and open it from cmd prompt?

Something like:

```
C:\path\to\directory
$ subl newfile myfile.txt
```

I'm on a Windows 7 machine and using [Cmder](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder) if that's something relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in batch you can simply:

```
copy nul myfile.txt
:: or
echo >myfile.txt
```

Oh wait, you can directly create file by opening it. Then you have to save it in subl

```
subl myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

From another perspective I found a working solution, but I'm curious to know if someone else can provide another answer!

For now I use the [fsutil](http://ss64.com/nt/fsutil.html) in windows to create the file, and then call Sublime to open the file like this:

```
C:\path\to\directory
$ fsutil file createnew myfile.ext 0
```

This will [create a new empty](http://www.windows-commandline.com/create-empty-file/) file with specified name and extension.

Then I call Sublime to open it like this:

```
C:\path\to\directory
$ subl myfile.ext --add
```

the `--add` flag opens the file in Sublime text without creating a new window.

Using the handy [alias feature of Cmder](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder#aliases) I chained the 2 commands in a single line:

```
C:\path\to\directory
$ alias snf=fsutil file createnew $1 0 $T subl $1 --add
```

Here `snf` is the alias I created `$1` is the variable parameter (the file name you want to create), $T is the command separator to concatenate multiple commands in the alias construct. You can read more with the `alias /?` command.